# Copy data from another cell if criteria is met

Tags: excel

I have quite a problem. In the excel spreadsheets, I have a lot of data entered into one main spreadsheet and some of the into another.

In the main Spreadsheet (Sheet1), I have column L, that has tons of entries of unique numbers. Also, I have a column Q that stores another data for a lot of entries into the sheet. 
In another sheet (Sheet2), I might have some of the entries that can be the same with the column L in the Sheet1, and they are stored in column D, on Sheet2. So, if those two sheets entries matches (L:L in Sheet1 with D:D in Sheet2), I want to have the Q entry from Sheet1 into my, lets say N column at Sheet2. If they don't match, blank would be ok.

I've been searching the solution for quite a time, found some on Microsoft official website, but I haven't been able to apply it.

[This one](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/office/forum/office_2007-excel/copy-data-from-one-sheet-to-another-if-criteria/1834f3b6-9b5a-e011-8dfc-68b599b31bf5?auth=1) was the closest solution I could find, but, since I'm newbie with Excel, I haven't been able to implement it correctly.

Edit:
To Illustrate a bit, here is exactly what I am looking for:

Lets say:

Sheet1

L2=115457; Q2=2148446

L3=381493; Q3=Blank

L4=121214; Q4=484846

L5=151515; Q5=Blank

Sheet2

D143=381493; N143=(need input from Q2)

D523=121214; N523=(need input from Q4)

D968=151515; N968=(Blank)

Thanks in advance.

Comment: A simple VLOOKUP will do it.

Comment: Could you provide a sample of your data?